# LOAD DATA stuck at Null State MySQL

Tags: mysql, innodb, performance, insert, bulk-insert, query-performance

I'm stuck trying to move one table to another, due to columns now no longer having proper references/meaning to their column titles. In doing this, I've created a new table with the same number of columns as the original, simply with the column names changed to better reflect the data coming in.

My problem is, the data is over 50 million rows, so I'm unable to simply alter the columns in place, so I've made a new table that I wish to use moving forward anyway. I've made the necessary column changes, but now when I try to load the data in, it looks like the process is simply stick.

+-----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id  | User | Host      | db       | Command | Time | State | Info                                                                                                 |
+-----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 481 | root | localhost | database | Query   | 8617 | NULL  | LOAD DATA  LOCAL INFILE '/home/SQLBackUps/file.csv' INTO TABLE `tablename` FIELDS   |
| 483 | root | localhost | database | Sleep   | 7174 |       | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 485 | root | localhost | database | Query   |    0 | NULL  | show processlist                                                                                     |
+-----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I ran the talk using mysqlimport with the necessary flags, so it should in theory at least be running, but as the state says null, I'm not sure what that really means as NULL, according to the documentation, only appears for show processlist. The file's permissions are as follows:

```
-rw-rw-rw-  1 mysql mysql 14141022004 May 15 16:42 file.csv
```

The file was created using SELECT INTO OUTFILE ...

Is there anything I can do to speed up this process? Right now it's on a very limited Dev machine with 2GB of RAM and an okay processor, so I understand it will take a bit of time, but given it's been over 2 hours and it's still in a null state, I'm stuck wondering if something is wrong, or if there is anything I can do to speed this process up.

Are there other ways to import the data quickly? Are there any flags I can use to speed this process up? Any, and all help is appreciated.

Update:

I started the process again in the very early morning, and have let it run for about 7 and a half hours now, and the process list looks as follows:

```
mysql> show processlist;
+----+------+-----------+------+---------+-------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id | User | Host      | db   | Command | Time  | State | Info                                                                                                 |
+----+------+-----------+------+---------+-------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  9 | root | localhost | db   | Query   | 22978 | NULL  | LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/SQLBackUps/file.csv' INTO TABLE table FIELDS TERMINATED |
| 15 | root | localhost | db   | Query   |     0 | NULL  | show processlist                                                                                     |
+----+------+-----------+------+---------+-------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Three questions: 1) Is binary logging enabled? 2) Is the DB Server you are loading a Replication Master ? 3) Is the table you are loading InnoDB ?

Comment: 1) I disabled binary logging for the duration of the application running, given that I knew that would slow everything down.

2) No, it's loading a .csv file that I created via SELECT INTO OUTFILE ... I'll update the question with the permissions on that file.

3) Yeah, it's an InnoDB. I turned off that FOREIGN_KEYS_CHECK value globally while this ran, and it's still slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one thing that caught my eye when you replied to my comment: The target table is InnoDB and you are using LOAD DATA INFILE. I see two issues

## ISSUE #1 : [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html)

While [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) can load InnoDB tables, that command can be tuned for loading MyYSAM tables. There is only one option to do this: [bulk_insert_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_bulk_insert_buffer_size). either setting to very large or setting it to zero to disable it.

There is no synonymous provision for InnoDB.

## ISSUE #2 : InnoDB Storage Engine

Let's take a look at the InnoDB Architecture

[image: InnoDB Architecture]

Now, picture yourself pushing 50 millions rows into one InnoDB table as a single transaction giving all the plumbing depicted in this elaborate illustration.

To ensure data consistency in the event of a crash, your data has to be written in three places:

- There are [128 rollback segments](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_undo_logs) in the System Tablespace (Physical File ibdata1). Your ***incoming table data must pile up on one Rollback Segment*** like [defensive tackles on a quarterback](http://ts3.mm.bing.net/th?id=HN.607990609882384702&pid=15.1).
- You have an active Double Write Buffer in the System Tablespace. As the name implies, data is being written twice. InnoDB will write to the Double Write Buffer first before writing back to the `.ibd` files. Those data are used as source data for crash recovery.
- The data are also being written in the Transaction Logs (Redo Logs in the Bottom Right Corner) via the Log Buffer. The physical files are ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1.

## My Perspective

InnoDB can handle 1024 current transactions but there are only 128 rollback segments. If there are other transactions going on, you got a New York City traffic jam on your hands. With all the InnoDB Internals to manage through your bulk insert, seeing NULL in the processlist should not be a surprise. You should look at four(4) things to make sure they are up-to-date:

1. filesize of ibdata1
2. timestamp on ibdata1
3. timestamp on ib_logfile0
4. timestamp on ib_logfile1

## SUGGESTIONS

You could set one or more of the following

- Disable the Double Write Buffer (set [**innodb_doublewrite**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_doublewrite) to 0). please set it back to 1 afterwards.
- Increase the InnoDB Buffer Pool (increase [**innodb_buffer_pool_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size))
- Increase the InnoDB Log File Size (set [**inndo_log_file_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size) to 2G)
- Increase the InnoDB Log Buffer Size (set [**inndo_log_buffer_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_buffer_size) to 512M)
- Change Transaction Flush Behavior (set [**innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit) to 0). This will disables ACID Compliance (could lost 1 second of transactions upon a crash) but will increase InnoDB Write Performance.
- Increase Write IO Thread (set [**innodb_write_io_threads**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_write_io_threads) to 64. You may as well set [**innodb_write_io_threads**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_read_io_threads) to 64)

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: I'll see about giving all of the above ago. After running the script as it is for the last 8 hours and no real progress it looks, this'll be my next go to attempt. If it works, I'll pop back and take it as the accepted.

Comment: I just added one suggestion

Comment: Thinking on it, I'm also considering trying this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463602/mysql-load-data-infile-acceleration

Will anything from that answer and yours combined interact badly? It doesn't appear so, but I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Since it is a single command, you don't need to need to  disable autocommit.

Comment: That's what I figured, I was thinking more along the unique check and foreign check. I already have the binary logs disabled at the moment, given I knew that would create a massive headache.